# Quicksort in R: How do I print the intermediate steps?

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I admit my knowledge of algorithms isn't very good. I wrote a quicksort function in R using basic recursion. My question is, how do I modify this algorithm to also display the intermediate vectors between each iteration. I know there is a clever way to do it with tracking where your pivot is but I'm struggling to figure it out myself.

```
qs <- function(vec) {

  if(length(vec) > 1) {

    pivot <- vec[1]

    low <- qs(vec[vec < pivot])
    mid <- vec[vec == pivot]
    high <- qs(vec[vec > pivot])

    c(low, mid, high)


  }

  else vec

}
```

Comment: may be by using `print`

Comment: Umm that wouldn't work since the algorithm is recursive. It sorts every sub-list until its one character long. I want to print each full vector during each iteration of sorting.

Comment: Do you have a small reproductible example to help us play with your function and try things...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. I posted my current recursive function. I'm looking to run the quicksort algorithm on a vector I passed but have it return every intermediate vector along the way. Sort of like some of the animations here: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Answer (score 1):

**PS:** I am not sure, but your implementation might be very inefficient depending on how R implements subscripting with a logical array.

You cannot do it without spending too much memory in it in the current state (i.e. using recursion).

**If you want to keep recursion:**
This is depth first approach. Initialize an array of arrays. The first index is the depth and the corresponding array would give you the state at that depth. Keep track of depth (i.e. pass depth as a parameter) and append the subarray to the corresponding depth.

Code:

```
printableList = Array of empty arrays 
qs <- function(vec, depth) {
printableList[depth] = printableList[depth] + vec

  if(length(vec) > 1) {
    pivot <- vec[1]
    low <- qs(vec[vec < pivot], depth+1)
    mid <- vec[vec == pivot]
    high <- qs(vec[vec > pivot], depth+1)

    c(low, mid, high)
  }
  else vec
}
```

**Alternatively:**
You can also implement the whole thing as a breadth first approach. You will have to implement the whole thing with a queue. Here, since you process the sub-problems layer-by-layer you just have to print them.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see it. Do you mind mocking up some pseudo code for this?

Answer (score 0):

As @dickoa noted, use `print`. However, if you're using the GUI, printed output is by default buffered until the function returns. You can force the printout to occur immediately with `flush.console`.

```
qs <- function(vec) {

  # print input vector
  print(vec); flush.console()

  if(length(vec) > 1) {

    pivot <- vec[1]

    low <- qs(vec[vec < pivot])
    mid <- vec[vec == pivot]
    high <- qs(vec[vec > pivot])

    c(low, mid, high)


  }

  else vec

}
```

Sample run:

```
> z <- sample(10)
> qs(z)
 [1]  2  6  1  4  8  5  9  7  3 10
[1] 1
[1]  6  4  8  5  9  7  3 10
[1] 4 5 3
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1]  8  9  7 10
[1] 7
[1]  9 10
integer(0)
[1] 10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: I want to have it spit out (or store in a list) the WHOLE vector during each iteration of the quicksort. Your method only passes through the current partition going through the quicksort recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing the whole vector at each function call, together with "start" and "end" parameters to describe which slice of the vector you're currently sorting.  Here's my first attempt at doing this.  Maybe you can write a more elegant version?

```
qs<-function(vec,start=1,finish=length(vec)) {
  if (finish>start) {
    pivot<-vec[start]
    N<-length(vec)
    window<-((1:N)>=start) & ((1:N)<=finish)
    low_part<-vec[(vec<pivot) & window]
    mid_part<-vec[(vec==pivot) & window]
    high_part<-vec[(vec>pivot) & window]

    if (start>1) cat(vec[1:(start-1)],"| ")
    cat(low_part,">>>",mid_part,"<<<",high_part)
    if (finish<N) cat(" |",vec[(finish+1):N])
    cat("\n")

    vec[window]<-c(low_part,mid_part,high_part)
    if (length(low_part)>0) {
      low_top<-start+length(low_part)-1
      vec[start:low_top]<-qs(vec,start,low_top)[start:low_top]
    }
    if (length(high_part)>0) {
      high_bottom<-finish-length(high_part)+1
      vec[high_bottom:finish]<-qs(vec,high_bottom,finish)[high_bottom:finish]
    }
  }
  return(vec)
}

qs(sample(1:30,replace=TRUE))
```