# Implementing in-place modification algorithms in R

Tags: r, algorithm

Just starting to learn R and immediately I am confused:

Given how everyone here (on SO) keeps saying that pass-by-value is one of the main R paradigms, is it possible to effectively implement algorithms that imply "modify in place" (aka quicksort and the likes)? The way I see it - if I do this using R I will have to return intermediate results effectively copying where in another language I will just modify an array passed by pointer/reference.  Am I missing something?

I understand it may be the wrong language for that but is it really so?

Comment: What do you mean by "modify in place", what do you want to do? Maybe [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Pass-By-Value-Questions-td2331565.html) can help you

Comment: I mean - algorithms that operate directly on an array of data instead of returning the result from a function to assign to a variable.(which  means - copying data and losing the whole point of such algos)

Comment: Great question – just note that quicksort is *not* an in-place algorithm, that’s a common misunderstanding (quicksort always needs additional space in the form of the call stack).

Comment: @Llopis [“in-place (modification)” has a well-defined meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) in the context of programming.

Comment: Read what [hadley has to say](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification) about modification in place or a copy in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thannks, I lack of formal programming formation :(. 
I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604579/quicksort-in-r-how-do-i-print-the-intermediate-steps) about the quicksort in R, or [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#R) from rosetta.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks, I was not consciously aware of the fact that stack consumption makes it not "in place" :) it definitely is an interesting observation

Comment: @Zeks, reading a bit about [functional programming paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)) should give some idea.

Comment: Worth noting that `data.table`'s internal modification routines modify data in-place. Not generally useful, but *very* useful if you're interested in tablular data.

Answer (score 6):

There are two main approaches. If you have control over the calling convention, you can wrap your objects in environments.

```
pointer <- new.env()
pointer$data <- iris
fn1 <- function(env) {
  numcols <- sapply(env$data, is.numeric)
  env$data[, numcols] <- env$data[, numcols] + 1
}
fn1(pointer) # pointer$data will now contain iris with all the numeric columns
             # incremented by 1. The full data set was never passed.
```

If you don't have control, you can try something sneakier with non-standard evaluation, but beware.

```
fn2 <- function(data) {
  numcols <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
  eval.parent(substitute(data[, numcols] <- data[, numcols] + 1))
}
fn2(iris)  # iris will now contain iris with all the numeric columns
           # incremented by 1. The full data set was also never passed.
```

In version 3.1 of R, copy on write will include the ability to handle *nested structures*, so the above two would be equivalent to simply

```
fn3 <- function(data) {
  numcols <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
  data[, numcols] <- data[, numcols] + 1
  data
}
iris <- fn3(iris)
```

If you have R 3.1 installed, you can verify the performance claims yourself by using `microbenchmark` on these three functions.

Comment: but doesn't copy-on-write get triggered in the last piece of code? We are essentially modifying data

Comment: Only on columns, which is what would have happened anyway even if you did not wrap it in a function. It does not, for example, copy the last (factor) column.

Comment: but if we sort an array then we can assume that it is a (nrow ,1)  frame structure and this means that copy on write gets triggered for all data ... ?

Comment: Correct, sorting does trigger a fully copy. This is unavoidable given R's internal list storage mechanism.