# Layer appending operator for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, eval

I love `ggplot2`, but I'd   prefer not to write `myplot <- myplot +`    each    time I add a layer. For example,

```r
# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Create plot
myplot <- ggplot(iris) 
myplot <- myplot + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
myplot <- myplot + ggtitle("This is a plot")
myplot <- myplot + theme_dark()
myplot
```

[image]

So, I wanted to create something similar to the additive compound assignment operator in C (`+=`).

```r
# Operator for appending layer
`%+=%` <- function(g, l){
  eval.parent(substitute(g <- g + l))
}

# Test appending function
myplot2 <- ggplot(iris) 
myplot2 %+=% geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
myplot2 %+=% ggtitle("This is a plot")
myplot2 %+=% theme_dark()
myplot2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, it gives the same result as the longhand syntax. This is approach is adapted from a solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23895219/1552004) to a different question and is accompanied by a word of warning; however, it's not clear to me why this is potentially problematic.

My question: what are the potential detrimental or unexpected side effects of defining an operator like above? Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from simply stringing together multiple `+` operations at once, with each new layer on a separate line. This keeps code tidy without having to assign each new addition back into `myplot`. This is how most ggplot code is presented.

Comment: @jdobres That's true, but there could feasibly be occasions where a layer has to be added later on (i.e., not when everything else is added). In these cases, what would be the problems associated with the `%+=%` operator as defined above?

Comment: For clarity, most people would use `myplot <-  ggplot(iris) +
geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
 + ggtitle("This is a plot")
 + theme_dark()`. I don't see anything particularly risky about your version. It might be a *little* less efficient, but that's usually not a big concern in defining ggplots.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- Okay, thanks. (I realise my code doesn't really need the operator, as jdrobes also points out, but I wanted to provide a succinct example.)

Comment: @Downvoter If you could explain how I could improve my question, I'd be grateful for the constructive criticism.

Comment: As an additional reference point, `magrittr` defines a similar pipe, `%<>%`, which [is defined similarly](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/R/pipe.R#L48). I don't have enough practical experience with calls and such to provide a more thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only downside I can honestly say is that your constructor is not as flexible as ggplot's.
ggplot already has an overloaded operator `+` which doesn't work intuitively with your function. Take this for an example:

```
gg <- ggplot(iris)
gg %+=% geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + theme_dark() #plots similar to your answer
   # only geom_point was added to gg variable
   #in other words the expression above is doing this
gg <- ggplot(iris)
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
gg + theme_dark()
```

This is a result of Infix functions which are always evaluated left to right. Thus unless you were able to capture the rest of the expression then there is little hope with using your function with ggplot's `+`

In it's current state you are only able to assign a layer one at a time which is arguably less efficient/tidy than doing

```
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) +
    ggtitle("This is a plot") +
    theme_dark()
```

It is also unusable with itself, but if you recode it as such:

```
`%+=%` <- function(g, l) {
  UseMethod("%+=%")
}

`%+=%.gg` <- function(g, l){
  gg.name <- deparse(substitute(g))
  gg.name <- strsplit(gg.name, split = "%+=%", fixed= T)[[1]][1]
  gg.name <- gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "", x = gg.name)
  gg <- g +l
  assign(x = gg.name, value = gg, envir = parent.frame())
}

gg <- ggplot(iris)
gg %+=% geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) %+=% theme_dark() #will now save left to right
```

I am really just being nit picky, but if your intent is to use this by adding a layer once at a time, then by all means your original function seems to work fine.